# How to rectify SMTP connection failure error?

Tags: php, smtp

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.comcast.net';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mass.mari06@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '8489328117';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = $SmtpPort;

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('mass.mari06@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('deeparavisankar93@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';



if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}


?>
```

****ERROR:****  Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

So what can I do? Please help me.. this code I downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: I hope that is not your real GMail credentials!

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is mail sending server.
You should use the one you are trying to send mail "from" is assigned. I assumed that you try to send from `mass.mari06@gmail.com` so configuration should look like following:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mass.mari06@gmail.com';
```